# How adjust the dynamically the height of a view based on height of stackview?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, storyboard

I have a problem with one of my VC. I need to resize a view depending on the height size of the stack view because the stack view have 2 textedit but in some cases one of them it's hidden.

Here is the view that contains the stackview this one needs to adjust the height depending on the height of the stackview
[image: Container View]

Here is the stackview contents, the stackview adjust perfectly depending if one of the textedit it's hidden or not but content view not, only leave the blank space under the stackview
[image: StackView]

These are the constraints of the container view.
[image: Constraints of the container view]

Any suggestion to achieve the goal (?)

Comment: Stack view adjusts its size according to its content. You just need to remove height set to stack view.

Comment: To clarify, your screen-shots show that you've given your `Card view` a Height constraint of `390`. If you want that height to be controlled by the stack view, remove that height constraint.

Answer (score -1):

Please share the screenshot for constraints so I can guide you better?
What we do is we don't give any height constraint to the stack view. The views at the top and bottom then adjust themselves when the stack changes its height due to the subview hidden/show.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).